# Missing javax classes in Android

Tags: java, android, libraries

I need to import a JDBC driver into my project, but it uses a handful of classes Android doesn't provide by default, such as javax.naming.* . I've tried to import those as an external library, but they in turn reference multiple other libraries (com.sun.naming.*,com.sun.jndi and so on) as well, rendering this approach impossible to succeed.

Question: what is the best way to approach this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: The best way to approach the problem is not to use JDBC in an Android app. Have your Android app work with a Web service or similar sort of application server, which in turn works with the database.

Comment: Jdbc needs javax.naming?

Comment: The driver for the database does, yes. javax.naming.* also is used when instantiating the DataSource in particular.

Answer (score 1):

There is no best way for solving your problem. Unfortunately, JDBC is not used with Android, so the best way is not use it. There are many other database solutions to work with.

IMHO, I certainly would not recommend it. Why? Because JDBC is designed for high-bandwidth, low-latency, highly-reliable network connections. For example, desktop to database server, Web application server to database server and so on. Mobile devices offer little of these, and none of them consistently.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It does. I've run into conflicting statements about this issue here, ranging from "it works perfectly" to "burn for even thinking about it", so finally decided to give it a test try since it could've been the easiest solution. It clearly isn't anymore. Thanks for saving me some time!